# Добавить данные в бд c#

Tags: c#, sql

Доброго времени суток!
Такая проблема, добавляю данные в таблицу, ошибка не выскакивает. Открываю таблицу в DataGridView(в другой форме), занесенные данные отображаются, но при закрытии программы и открытии заново, данных нет

Добавление

```
connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; 
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbmdf.mdf; Integrated 
Security=True");
connect.Open();            
string sql = "INSERT INTO book (IdBook, NameBook, AuthorBook, Year, 
Section) VALUES (@id, @name, @author, @year, @section)";
SqlCommand cmd_SQL = new SqlCommand(sql, connect);
cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idBook.Text);
cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", tbYear.Text);
cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", tbName.Text);
cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", tbAutor.Text);
cmd_SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", tbSection.Text);

try
{
    cmd_SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Error.Text = "Даннык занесены";
    Error.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    Error.Show();
    idBook.Text = "";
    tbAutor.Text = "";
    tbName.Text = "";
    tbSection.Text = "";
    tbYear.Text = "";
}
catch (Exception)
{    
    Error.Text = "Данные не занесены";
    Error.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    Error.Show();
}
connect.Close();
```

Comment: Не по существу вопроса, но `connect.Close();` надо бы размещать в блоке `finally`.

Comment: Учту, но хотелось бы по теме:)

Comment: Попробуйте проверить так: `int rowAffected =   cmd_SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();` и на след. строку точку останова поставьте и посмотрите значение `rowAffected`.

Comment: Я закрою как дубликат, т.к. по симптомам у вас именно эта проблема. А вообще connect.Close не нужно размещать в блоке finally. Вместо этого надо оборачивать использование SqlConnection в using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Полагаю происходит следующее, база лежит в корне проекта, изначально пустая, при компиляции она копируется в папку Debug и работа в программе происходит с копией базы, при перезапуске ваша база с данными заменяется на изначальную. Сам особо не работал с БД непосредственно в студии, но полагаю нужно вытащить файл с базой из корня и обращаться к нему по новому пути.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, проблема была в этом